# please help meeeee installing packages/software

Tags: drivers, system-installation, package-management

i just started using Ubuntu i was using cyborg hawk but was forced to switch due to my hardware switch would never turn on or so thats what it said wifi works perfect with everything elese i bought a alfa with a 10dbi antenna it work  fine on Ubuntu. but anyways all the pen testing tools were conveniatly pre installed websploit, metasploit, DoD attack tools, ect.... now im on Ubuntu i have none and i tried to go and install them from the website but for the life of me i cant figure out how to install ANYTHING!! on Ubuntu  not even the drivers for my new ralink wifi dongle please help me im going crazy lol
and i really like Ubuntu

Comment: I can't understand this

Comment: He wants to have the same penetration apps that he had when using Cyborg Hawk, but he does not know how to install them.

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of options to install a program in Ubuntu. First, if you are lucky, the program might be in the repositories, which means you have easy access to them. Say you want to install `websploit`. To do so, open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

`sudo apt-get install websploit`

If the program is available from the repositories, it will install. If not, you will get a message saying:

`E: Unable to locate package websploit`

Note that you can install many programs at the same time by writing:

`sudo apt-get install program1 program2 program3 ...`

If the above method does not work, you can manually install that package by downloading a .deb file (maybe it will be inside a zip or tar file). For example, you can find Websploit [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/websploit/). Download the file and extract into a folder. Then open a terminal as above, navigate to the directory where you extracted the program (using `cd ~/folder/of/my/program/`), and run:

```
sudo dpkg -i file.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

After this, your program will be installed and ready to run.

Just do the same for all the other programs that are not available through the Ubuntu repositories.